# Should a function return a "new" object

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return, heap-memory

Should a function to return a pointer to memory allocated on the heap?

In other words, which of the following methods is more "correct"?

```
// Method #1
Object* getObject1() {
    return new Object();
}

// Method #2
std::shared_ptr<Object> getObject2() {
    return std::make_shared<Object>();
}

int main() {
    // Usage of method #1
    Object* o1 = getObject1();
    o1->doSomething();
    delete o1; // object has to be deleted by user

    // Usage of method #2
    std::shared_ptr<Object>& o2 getObject2(); // has to be kept in shared_ptr
    o2.get()->doSomething();
    // object is deleted when o2 destructs
}
```

I imagine the first method is probably faster, but the second method does not require the user to delete the object.

Comment: Why should the first method be "faster"? Are you trying to call it a million times per second in a tight loop?

Comment: The first solution doesn't have a place in modern c++. At the very least, it should create and return a `std::unique_ptr<Object>`.

Comment: There's also method 3, return `std::unique_ptr<Object>`. If unsure, do that. There is no overhead, and you can always convert a unique pointer to a shared pointer (consuming it in the process). Also, you cannot forget to delete a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: __Herb Sutter - Object Factories__:  https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/

Comment: @ChristianHackl, why not?

Comment: Note you can write just `o2->doSomething();` rather than `o2.get()->doSomething();`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of the two, the second would be preferred. Naked pointers should always be your last choice. But ideally, you would just return `Object` by value. Failing that, a `unique_ptr` would be better than a `shared_ptr` unless you really do need shared ownership.

> I imagine the first method is probably faster.

That's probably true with `shared_ptr`. But with `unique_ptr`, the compiler can optimize. There's no benefit that pays you back for the risk of manual deletion.

Comment: +1 for *"ideally, you would just return `Object` by value."*.    People who are less familiar with C++ sometimes don't realise that returning an object by-value is usually [optimised to eliminate temporary objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), and therefore more efficient than returning a pointer to a heap-allocated object.

Comment: @BenCottrell Especially with proper use of move semantics. It's sometimes more efficient, often equal in cost, and only very rarely more expensive (assuming sanely designed classes). And even in those rare cases where it's more expensive, it's often still worth it to get value semantics that are simple and intuitive.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you say: "Naked pointers should always be your last choice", surely there is a case where returning an `Object*` is better. For example when you don't expect the user to take ownership.

Comment: @DutChen18 I would try everything else first, for example, returning a reference.

Comment: @DutChen18 in that situation, I would be more inclined to return `Object&` and throw an exception if I had nothing to return (as opposed to using `Object*` with the intention of returning `nullptr`, since the most common usage I've seen when returning `nullptr` usually looks like an error-return-code in stealth)

Answer (score 4):

Neither option is really that great.

By default, the best thing you can do in C++ is this:

```
Object getObject1() {
    return Object();
}
```

If you really *have* to use dynamic allocation, then your first choice should be returning a `std::unique_ptr` by value:

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> getObject1() {
    return std::make_unique<Object>();
}
```

See ["GotW #90 Solution: Factories" by Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/) for a nice article on that subject. Among other things, Sutter says:

> - Returning unique_ptr expresses returning unique ownership, which is
>     the norm for a pure “source” factory function.
> - unique_ptr can’t be beat in efficiency—moving one is about as cheap as moving/copying a raw pointer.

As for your specific questions:

> I imagine the first method is probably faster,

`std::shared_ptr` involves locking in order to be thread-safe, so it may potentially decrease performance. However, it should not really matter. Dynamic allocation is typically always slower than the alternative, so you typically do not want to use it where micro performance matters (such as in a tight loop or in some part of the code which is executed many times per second). C++ discourages you from creating many small objects on the free store. So a function like this should not be able to be a bottleneck in the first place.

Comment: I was thinking about this problem for quite a while. All solutions I found so far are not ideal in my view. I'd like like it to be concise from the usage perspective and scalable from providing but cannot figure out a complete solution yet. On the consuming side I'd like it to look like auto obj = ClassName::Create<allocator<unique_ptr>>(....) or you could do auto obj = ClassName::Create<allocator<local_val>>(....). On providing side you implement that allocator and associate it with unique_ptr or shared_ptr or local_val or whatever. I'm not yet able to create such templates.

Answer (score 1):

All of them are correctly. However, it's a good practice to create a "deleter" function for the first case...

why?

because you have an "interface" that's responsible allocating the object, then you should have another pair that does the deallocation, once the consumer of this function is using your interface, one doesn't need to know that a `new` is happening inside... it could be a `malloc`, for example, or anything else... so the pair of deleter function would implement the `delete` or `free` or whatever else you have to proper deallocate.